# How to recursively inject props to each React component in a tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I've been using `emotion-js` for a while, and I love it! But I really hate e2e tests for that. All selectors look like this: `div > div > div > p`, because `emotion` injects classnames which are random-generated strings.
So I thought of injecting `data-` attributes with `DisplayName` to each element to be able to test them in more clean way: `[data-test-id*="DateButton"]` or something like that. So I wrote this simple wrapper:
https://gist.github.com/sergeyvlakh/3072a4e2e27456bda853a1e1a213a568

And I use it like this:

```
import Injector from './injector';

export default props => 
    (
        <Injector>
            <MyReactTree />
        </Injector>
    )
```

The problem here is what I'm not "dynamically" inject data attribute. I want to use it like any HoC from `recompose`:
`export default Injector(App)`

OR even with dynamic prop name like: `export default Injector('data-test-id')(App)`.
But...children for `Injector` will be undefined in that case, so I don't know how to proceed :)

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to [remix23](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8520481/remix23) I did this way: https://gist.github.com/sergeyvlakh/f99310cdef018c06451333a36e764372

However I strongly recommend to use his code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject props to any React element by using [`React.cloneElement(element, newPropsToMerge, newChildren)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)

You can do it recursively to follow chilren in depth by accessing each element children and so forth.

And maybe more costly but more straightforward this should work also:

```
    function Injector(Target) {
         class InjectedTarget extends Component {
              render() {
                  const { chilren, ...rest } = this.props;
                  return (
                      <Target
                          data-test-id={Target.DisplayName}
                          {...rest}
                      >
                          {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
                              const isComponent = 
                                  child &&
                                  child.type &&
                                  typeof child.type !== 'string' && 
                                  Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.apply(
                                      React.Component.prototype,
                                      [child.type.prototype]
                                  );
                              if (!isComponent) {
                                  return child;
                              }
                              return React.createElement(Injector(child.type), { ...child.props, 'data-test-id': Target.DisplayName });
                          })}
                      </Target>
                  );
              }
         }
         return InjectedTarget;
    }
```

I think that will be awfull performance wise, but this is for testing right?

Comment: Like I said, if I wrap component like HoC: `Injector(App)`, Injector will have no children, as it's not jsx

Comment: Yes you will. In the Injector HOC you will at some point render App. So you can set the props you like in App. Then you can have access the children props (if there are children) and do a `React.Children.map(props.chilren, child => Reactg.cloneElement(child, { 'data-test-id': ... }))`.
I'm updating the answer

Comment: No, I don't agree with you.
Lets say we have this code:
```
const Injector = App => {
  return class Wrapped extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
      const r = <App />
      return <App />
    }
  }
}
```
The r will be ReactComponent, however `props.children` will be empty there.

Comment: A-ha! Got it! I need to render my decorated component first to get access to `props.children`

Comment: Also, I don't need to clone anything, since I can just render it, store it as React component and then run `React.Children.map` against this variable!

Comment: I did not clone to recursively use the HOC, but I could have cloned the children recursively without re-injecting the HOC at each stage.

Comment: here is how I did this: https://gist.github.com/sergeyvlakh/f99310cdef018c06451333a36e764372